# How to pass additional arguments int state entry or exit function in boost MSM

Tags: boost, state-machine

I want to provide my own function arguments in the Boost.MSM state entry or exit function. Is that possible?

For example, the original example is:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(state_entry)
{
  template <class Event, class Fsm, class State>
  void operator()(const Event &ev, Fsm &fsm, State &state) const
  {
    std::cout << "Entering\n";
  }
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(state_exit)
{
  template <class Event, class Fsm, class State>
  void operator()(const Event &ev, Fsm &fsm, State &state) const
  {
    std::cout << "Exiting\n";
  }
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((state_entry, state_exit), Off)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((state_entry, state_exit), On)
```

What I want is something like:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(state_entry)
{
  template <class Event, class Fsm, class State>
  void operator()(const Event &ev, Fsm &fsm, State &state, int n) const
  {
    std::cout << "Entering\n";
  }
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((state_entry(100), state_exit), Off)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is possible. But from what i know you have to declare that attribute outside those functions.
For example, first declare the new attribute:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_ATTRIBUTE(int, myValue)
```

And then pass this attribute on your state machine definition:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_STATE_MACHINE((yourSmTable, // the transition table
                                     init_ << InitialState, // the initial state
                                     no_action,       // no entry action defined
                                     no_action,       // no exit action defined
                                     attributes_ << myValue // add attribute to state machine
                                     ), YourStateMachine_)
```

Finally on your function state_entry, get the attribute myValue:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(state_entry)
{
    template <class Event, class Fsm, class State>
    void operator()(const Event &ev, Fsm &fsm, State &state, int n) const
    {
        std::cout << "Entering\n";
        int yourValue = fsm.get_attribute(myValue));
    }
};
```